# How to fix "Duplicate sources.list entry" warning?

Tags: apt, software-sources

Every time I try to do some update (`sudo apt-get update`) it says:

```
Reading package lists ... ready
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ need /partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ need /partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You have to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

sources.list: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1180190/

`ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as requested:

```
milton@milton-HuronRiver-Platform:~$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
emesene-team-emesene-stable-precise.list
precise-partner.list
precise-partner.list.save
upubuntu-com-chat-precise.list
upubuntu-com-chat-precise.list.save
```